# After updating Xamarin I get referenced component *** could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After Updating Xamarin Forms via NuGet I can't build my Android App anymore. This are the errors:

```
Error This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see ... The missing file is ..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.0.121934\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.props

Warning The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android' could not be found.
Warning The referenced component '***' could not be found. (for all my references except my own added reference "shared code")

Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.

Warning "\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.0.122203\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.props" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "\RajaChat.Android\RajaChat.Android.csproj (3,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored.
```

I already tried the following from answers here on stack overflow or xamarin forums:

- Deleting the package folder and let nuget restore restore the packets
- Using nuget console with: "Update-Package –reinstall"
- Clean Build and Rebuild with deleting obj and bin folders
- Downgrade to Xamarin.Build.Download 0.4.6
- Unload and Reload the Android Project

Nothing helped, always the same output...

I turned on the `TRACEDESIGNTIME` for debugging the `IDE0006 Error` but it only gave me the same error as above in the `*.designtime.log`:

```
\RajaChat\RajaChat\RajaChat.Android\RajaChat.Android.csproj(308,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see . The missing file is ..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.0.121934\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.props.
```

Using **Visual Studio 2017** and **Xamarin Forms 2.5.0.122203**
[image: error codes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your solution remove the nuget package `Xamarin.Forms`, in the `.csproj` of your Android project, remove the import (check if there are multiple references and delete them) of your `Xamarin.Forms` package.
 It should be something like:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.5.0.121934" />
```

And then remove the `Xamarin.Forms` package from the `packages` folder.
 
Now the solution should be free from `Xamarin.Forms` package references, add the `Xamarin.Forms` Nuget package and rebuild.

Comment: If still have errors: Unload project. Reload project, after you're done with nugets.

Comment: Wow hung here 3 days, that worked! I hadn't any `<PackageReference>` tags in the file but I deleted all tags where `Xamarin.Forms` occured. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the references and delete bin and object folders in .Droid. then save and re-open the solution. Wait few seconds for VS to download and add all references from nauget.